# How to receive a simple POST in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https

I "just" need to do a simple https server in ASP.NET Core in order to receive some XML streams through a POST verb.

I just have to write these XML on hard disk.

I don't really know where to begin to just running an ASP.NET Core server to get the POST data.

Anyone could give me some inputs or a sample code ? I don't need MVVM or something else, just getting POST data.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a starter app by running the command
`dotnet new webapi`
That will give you all the code needed to set up a server that can accept REST API calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the **MVC model** in ASP.NET Core, you can use the **Razor Pages model**. Please refer to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. For Post Form data you will have to write a OnPostAsync method in you Razor Page.